# Orientation not working correctly

Tags: ios, orientation, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm having some trouble getting my app's orientation to behave properly. In a nutshell, I have two view controllers that I will be switching between in my app. `ViewControllerA` should only be displayed in portrait or in upside down. `ViewControllerB` can be displayed in any of the four orientations.

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward. I wasn't sure exactly how to do it, but I figured if I just fiddled with `shouldAutorotate`, `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` then I should get what I want. For some reason, the interface orientations in `info.plist` are **completely** overriding any code in the view controller. If I only allow portrait in `info.plist` but allow everything in my viewcontroller, it *does not* rotate. And the only method that gets called is `supportedInterfaceOrientations` (in which I return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`). Likewise, if I allow every orientation in `info.plist`, rotating the device rotates the viewController as well, even though in my code I disallow any orientation that isn't portrait.

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Could someone please help out and show me the snippet of what my orientation code should look like for `ViewControllerA`, `ViewControllerB`, and what orientations should be selected in `info.plist`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On function

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

You should return true to all interfaces you want to rotate to, Let say you want portrait only

```
return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
```

if you want everything but upsideDown

```
return !(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
```

On plist itself it set more global values so your code wouldn't run if this option isn't available. You  must grant it on plist to be able to do this for two view.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method has been deprecated in iOS 6.  Instead implement the supportedInterfaceOrientations and shouldAutorotate methods in all your current full-screen view controllers.

Also make sure that your app does a setRootViewController on the main window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your AppDelegate.m

//[window_ addSubview:navController_.view];

[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];